# How to change values in a Pandas DataFrame based on values of another columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame with some numbers in them where the sum of the values in Col1, Col2, and Col3 is equal to the value in column Main.

How can I replace the values in the *Cat* columns if they are equal to the corresponding value in the *Main* column?

For example, the following DataFrame:

```
      Main        Col1        Col2        Col3
0     100         50          50          0
1     200         0           200         0
2     30          20          5           5
3     500         0           0           500
```

would be changed to this:

```
      Main        Col1        Col2        Col3
0     100         50          50          0
1     200         0           EQUAL       0
2     30          20          5           5
3     500         0           0           EQUAL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `filter` to apply only on the "Col" columns (you could also use slicing with a list, see alternative), then `mask` to change the matching values, finally `update` to update the DataFrame in place:

```
df.update(df.filter(like='Col').mask(df.eq(df['Main'], axis=0), 'EQUAL'))
```

Alternative:

```
cols = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']
df.update(df[cols].mask(df.eq(df['Main'], axis=0), 'EQUAL'))
```

Output:

```
   Main  Col1   Col2   Col3
0   100    50     50      0
1   200     0  EQUAL      0
2    30    20      5      5
3   500     0      0  EQUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways of doing this, I suggest using the `np.where()` function.

```
import numpy as np

df['Col1'] = np.where(df['Col1'] == df['Main'], 'EQUAL', df['Col1']
df['Col2'] = np.where(df['Col2'] == df['Main'], 'EQUAL', df['Col2']
df['Col3'] = np.where(df['Col3'] == df['Main'], 'EQUAL', df['Col3']
```

Read more about `np.where()` [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).